# Heroku process is supposed to always stay running, but when it gets pinged it crashes with an H20 error

Tags: java, heroku, gradle, intellij-idea, get

So I have a Java application running in Heroku where it's always listening for something. It's not supposed to be pinged, but if it does, it returns an H20 error because the process never ends. How can I prevent this?

I've tried listening for a `get` call:

```
get("", new Route() {
        @Override
        public Object handle(Request request, Response response) throws Exception {
            return "Hello";
        }
  });
```

But then realized that it's going to end the whole process, meaning it's no longer going to run until I do `heroku restart` because the process starts as soon as I publish.

What can I do to make the server ignore pings, without ending the process itself?

To make things clear, this is supposed to be a text bot listening for commands in a certain chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [H20](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h20-app-boot-timeout) is an App Boot Timeout.
For `web` process types, Heroku requires you to bind the port specified at $PORT. If after 75 seconds, your process isn't bound to that port, it is considered as too long to boot and therefore killed.

If your bot isn't meant to listen for HTTP requests, you can fix this changing the process type name from web to anything else in your [Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile).